# Wifi wont work in Samsung galaxy 3 even after a hard reset

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a samsung galaxy s3 which was in excellent condition when I sold it.  After 2 weeks, the buyer wanted a return, so, I got the phone back. Somehow, the wifi is not working. When I look at the firmware, it says 4.4.2 which believe is kit kat. It seems to me like he tried to hack it and now the wifi wont work. Plus, who knows which other program he altered? I end up paying him and end up with a phone I can't even use. Please help me. I followed the hard reset and it still wont fix the problem...:(

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.4.2 (Kitkat) was not officially released by Samsung for the Galaxy SIII.
You can search at [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) for your SIII (GT-I9300) and download the latest official firmware. (registration required but I can give you the links too, if you don't like to register there)
Then flash it using *Odin* (or similar) to get your stock firmware back.

> A private sale is free from any warranty by the seller, so you didn't even have to accept the return (in the EU at least).

Comment: Curious.  I have 4.4.2 on my S3 via Verizon.  Does your answer refer to non-US only?

Comment: The S3 by Verizon is not the I9300/international version. The international one has 1GB of RAM, only Android 4.3 and no 4G.

Comment: Ok, so, how could you tell that's what the OP has from the problem description?

Comment: He said that the buyer tried to *hack* it, so I assumed Android 4.4.2 is not the version that was on it before.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is going to involve reflashing the ROM by using ODIN. There is a website that has all Samsung firmwares in zip files available for download, just get one and find instructions to use ODIN to flash it. Just be very careful, you could make matters much worse if you don't use a compatible ROM or don't follow instructions perfectly.

If that doesn't work, then it must be a hardware problem. In that case, there's not much I can recommend... Perhaps taking the back off and screws out and checking that everything is connected properly.